# ASP.NET Docker UserSecrets location

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, docker

I have created an ASP.NET application that connects to microsoft sql database and needs a password for that. When running the application under Windows it takes the password from secrets.json file located in C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets<UserSecretsId>

When running under Docker I am unable to find out where I should put the secrets.json file. I tried /root/.microsoft/usersecrets/ as it seemed to work for others but no for me. Guess I am not among the lucky ones.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: When you say running under Docker are you still developing or is that "production"? Because you don't use user secrets in production, usually you will make them environment variables and by default the .NET core configuration system will pull them in automatically as long as you name them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using user secrets I would suggest you pass these values in as environmental variables. While it is possible to store user secrets inside a docker image, you'd be putting your secrets into a repository, which is not something you want to do. Instead, you can pass in the values as environmental variables when the docker run is performed. See [Environmental Variable Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#environment-variable-configuration-provider)